Source impedance-trace impedance - load termination impedance confusion
I drew an experiment PCB to better understand the PCB impedance. And when I look at the impedance at 1 GHz, it can be seen that it is 119 Ω at most points of the trace. Then, I created a source that produces a square wave with a period of 1 GHz (output 3.3 V). I set the internal impedance of this source to 0 Ω. And at the same time, a 119 Ω termination resistor was added to the output. However, there is something I don't understand. Normally,Zsource = Zline = Zload is required in impedance equalization situations to avoid reflection on the line. In this case, when we apply a 1ghz signal, shouldn't we think of it as a voltage divider of 119 Ω - 119 Ω? So the result we expect is 3.3V/2=1.65?
Can someone help clear up my confusion?








Did you mean Zline etc. instead of Vline etc.?

Yes ,thanks for the warning


Normally, Zsource = Zline = Zload is required in impedance
equalization situations to avoid reflection on the line.

You don't need the source to match the characteristic impedance of the line. The minimum set-up to avoid any reflection is that the load end is correctly terminated. This can further be modified by saying that to avoid destructive reflections, only the source end needs to be terminated.
In your case, the source is zero ohms hence the full voltage signal is applied to the transmission line and, if the line is efficient, then you can expect to see the same signal level at the terminated end of the line.
This is because at the instant you apply 3.3 volts directly to the line, the characteristic impedance (119 Ω) dictates that 27.7 mA flows. This is simple ohm's law.
When the 3.3 volts and 27.7 mA reach the far end of the line, the loading encountered is 119 Ω also. Hence, ohm's law is not in jeopardy and no reflection takes place AND, the load resistor (119 Ω) receives the full 3.3 volts and draws 27.7 mA.

No, the transmission line, if considered lossless, has zero resistance.
Therefore it does not divide voltage, when you drive it with 0 ohms.
So for a 3.3V waveform going into a PCB trace, will travel through the wire and comes out as a 3.3V waveform after the delay it takes to travel.
What the characteristic impedance of a PCB trace means, is that when you apply some voltage, some current starts to flow into the wire, and the ratio of this voltage and current is the transmission line characteristic impedance for the signal, which can be thought as the inifinitesimally small wire sections having inductance and capacitance, which is why Z0 ~ sqrt(L/C).
The termination resistor just makes the input of the transmission line to look continuous and infinite, because when the signal comes out from the transmission line, the same current at same voltage should flow out to resistor.
In the case of when driver output impedance to transmission line equals the characteristic impedance, the voltage gets already divided by the source impedance and transmission line impedance, as again, the transmission line draws some current at some voltage when signal goes into it and travels towards the output.
Basically, for steady state DC signals, the transmission line is 0 ohms, but for changing signals, it is a delay line and looks like a resistance with the characteristic impedance until the signal has reached the end of the delay line, and if it happend the delay line output has a termination resistor of characteristic impedance, the input will look like constant resistance no matter if the signal has traveled through the delay or not.

The normal condition you suggest is the double-termination condition. This tends to maximize bandwidth (an idealized simulation won't show anything, but a more realistic lossy and dispersive model may), and obviously (in light of the following) is more tolerant of mismatch, but has the downside of costing 6dB relative to the input voltage or drive strength.
The line needs to be terminated on at least one end, or standing waves result.  Consider a wave incident from port 1 terminated at Zo, towards port 2 terminated at 0 or ∞Ω.  A full reflection results (in opposite or same phase respectively), giving a VSWR of 2.  The reflected wave incident on port 1 is terminated and no further reflection results.  Likewise if a wave is incident from port 2 originally.
Your simulation shows good signal quality and full amplitude, because the source port is 0, launching a wave of equal amplitude, which is fully absorbed at the far end.  A practical driver will have a higher source impedance, so expect to need a receiver at the far end -- something that can handle the reduced amplitude, as a traditional LVCMOS input pin will not (but, one probably won't respond very well at 1GHz either).
More likely, the driver will be high impedance (current source), as with LVDS, and the receiver is basically a differential comparator.
